# Error Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I have this problem, I believe it's something in Json, but I've tried everything and I'm not able to return the objects.

My code:

```
        public List<Product> List()
        {
            var retorno = new List<Product>();
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://teste.teste1.com.br/app/Api/V1/Products/list"))
                    {
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-user-email", "victor@teste.com.br");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", "eyJ0edsasa3121dasdas312dsa");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-store-key", "1");
                        request.Content = new StringContent("Content-Type", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                        var response = client.SendAsync(request);
                        //var response = client.GetStringAsync(uprApi + "app/Api/V1/Products/list");
                        response.Wait();
                        retorno = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product[]>(response.Result.ToString()).ToList();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return retorno;
        }
```

Image Error:
[image: Error]

**EDIT:**

My json:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "offset": 0,
    "result": {
        "error": false,
        "registers_count": 5,
        "pages_count": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "product": {
                    "sku": "01",
                    "name": "Produto teste 01",
                    "description": "Produto de teste 01.",
                    "status": "enabled",
                    "qty": 30,
                    "price": 149.9,
                    "list_price": 199.9,
                    "weight_gross": 0.1,
                    "weight_liquid": 0.1,
                    "height": 1,
                    "width": 1,
                    "length": 1,
                    "items_per_package": "1",
                    "brand": "Colcci",
                    "ean": null,
                    "ncm": null,
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "code": "339",
                            "name": "ESPORTES/Academia e Fitness/Roupas"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "product": {
                    "sku": "3",
                    "name": "Produto DESATIVADO",
                    "description": "xyz",
                    "status": "disabled",
                    "qty": 0,
                    "price": 5.8,
                    "list_price": null,
                    "weight_gross": 0.1,
                    "weight_liquid": 0.1,
                    "height": 1,
                    "width": 1,
                    "length": 1,
                    "items_per_package": "1",
                    "brand": "Colcci",
                    "ean": null,
                    "ncm": null,
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "code": null,
                            "name": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "variation_attributes": [
                        "UN"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "product": {
                    "sku": "2",
                    "name": "Produto X",
                    "description": "xyz",
                    "status": "enabled",
                    "qty": 0,
                    "price": 5.8,
                    "list_price": null,
                    "weight_gross": 0.1,
                    "weight_liquid": 0.1,
                    "height": 1,
                    "width": 1,
                    "length": 1,
                    "items_per_package": "1",
                    "brand": "Colcci",
                    "ean": null,
                    "ncm": null,
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "code": null,
                            "name": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "variation_attributes": [
                        "UN"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "product": {
                    "sku": "1",
                    "name": "Produto",
                    "description": "Descrição do Produto Criado",
                    "status": "disabled",
                    "qty": 176,
                    "price": 5.9,
                    "list_price": 5.8,
                    "weight_gross": 0.1,
                    "weight_liquid": 0.1,
                    "height": 1,
                    "width": 1,
                    "length": 1,
                    "items_per_package": "1",
                    "brand": "Colcci",
                    "ean": "7896044963486",
                    "ncm": null,
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "code": "3",
                            "name": "FEMININO/Roupas/Blusas e Camisas"
                        }
                    ],
                    "variations": [
                        {
                            "sku": "P_B",
                            "qty": 12,
                            "EAN": null,
                            "price": 5.8,
                            "list_price": 5.8,
                            "images": [],
                            "variant": [
                                {
                                    "size": "p"
                                },
                                {
                                    "color": "Branco"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "sku": "M_P",
                            "qty": 14,
                            "EAN": null,
                            "price": 5.8,
                            "list_price": 5.8,
                            "images": [],
                            "variant": [
                                {
                                    "size": "m"
                                },
                                {
                                    "color": "Preto"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "sku": "ABC1",
                            "qty": 150,
                            "EAN": null,
                            "price": 5.9,
                            "list_price": 5.8,
                            "images": [],
                            "variant": [
                                {
                                    "size": "p"
                                },
                                {
                                    "color": "Azul"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "product": {
                    "sku": "GG004",
                    "name": "Gabinete Gamer",
                    "description": "Gabinete Gamer com RGB",
                    "status": "enabled",
                    "qty": 6,
                    "price": 399.9,
                    "list_price": 399.9,
                    "weight_gross": 0.3,
                    "weight_liquid": 0.25,
                    "height": 9,
                    "width": 3,
                    "length": 5,
                    "items_per_package": "1",
                    "brand": "Colcci",
                    "ean": null,
                    "ncm": null,
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "code": "276",
                            "name": "CELULARES & ELETRÔNICOS/Informática/Games"
                        }
                    ],
                    "images": [
                        "https://manairadigitalteste.conectala.com.br/app/assets/images/product_image/4B3451F8-C862-7884-D169-5F256FA31F91/16581443192118.jpg"
                    ],
                    "published_marketplace": {
                        "ManairaDigital": "5_ManairaDigital"
                    },
                    "marketplace_offer_links": [
                        {
                            "name": "ManairaDigital",
                            "href": "https://manairadigital.com.br/gabinete-gamer-29/p"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
HEADERS:

```
             {"x-user-email", "victor@manairadigital.com.br"},
             {"x-api-key", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjb2Rfc3RvcmUiOjMsImNvZF9jb21wYW55Ijo3fQ.E_sxhnwcmN5GtNGRYbVD66ciMi3JoJNjormS1q3mxYg"},
             {"x-store-key", "3"},
             {"Content-Type", "application/json"},
             {"accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
```

teste teste teste
teste teste teste
teste teste teste
teste teste teste
teste teste teste
teste teste teste
teste teste teste
teste teste teste
teste teste teste
teste teste teste
teste teste teste

**EDIT 3**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDzd4.png)

Comment: Probably your json input is invalid. Can you show it?

Comment: Aso, but unrelated: `response.Wait();` - that's a red flag. Go async all the way.

Comment: The `response.Result.ToString()` returns headers, status code etc but you need the body of the response.

Comment: I added edit with my json

Comment: ggeorge, how do i fix it?

Comment: eu tirei o "resultado" e compilar novamente e retornou o erro "System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The 'method' scheme is not supported.)'".  I think i'm doing it wrong yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all using `Wait` you have a synchronous code and will block the thread until the task completes. You should await the request so it will asynchronous wait the task to complete. Try this instead and mark async the method that wraps this request to get the json response asynchronously:

```
// You need to return an IEnumerable of products
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> ListAsync() 
{
     var client = new HttpClient
     {
         BaseAddress = new Uri("https://manairadigitalteste.conectala.com.br")
     };

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-user-email", "your-email");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", "your-key");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-store-key", "3");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    using var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/app/Api/V1/Products/list");
    req.Content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using var res = await client.SendAsync(req);    
    res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var responseBody= await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(responseBody);
    var output = new List<Product>();
    root?.result.data.ToList().ForEach(x => output.Add(x.product));
    return output;
}
```

Then paste json as classes from menu in visual studio `Edit->Paste Special->Paste JSON as classes`. If you do this will get these classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public bool error { get; set; }
    public int registers_count { get; set; }
    public int pages_count { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public Datum[] data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public Product product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public float price { get; set; }
    public float? list_price { get; set; }
    public float weight_gross { get; set; }
    public float weight_liquid { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public string items_per_package { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; }
    public string ean { get; set; }
    public object ncm { get; set; }
    public Category[] categories { get; set; }
    public string[] variation_attributes { get; set; }
    public Variation[] variations { get; set; }
    public string[] images { get; set; }
    public Published_Marketplace published_marketplace { get; set; }
    public Marketplace_Offer_Links[] marketplace_offer_links { get; set; }
}

public class Published_Marketplace
{
    public string ManairaDigital { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Variation
{
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public object EAN { get; set; }
    public float price { get; set; }
    public float list_price { get; set; }
    public object[] images { get; set; }
    public Variant[] variant { get; set; }
}

public class Variant
{
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}

public class Marketplace_Offer_Links
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
}
```

Last in your controller do this:

```
 // GET: ProdutosController
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var products = await _IProduto.ListAsync();
    return View(products);
}
```

**A note about HttpClient**:

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application. In .NET Core and .NET 5+, HttpClient pools connections inside the handler instance and reuses a connection across multiple requests. If you instantiate an HttpClient class for every request, the number of sockets available under heavy loads will be exhausted. This exhaustion will result in SocketException errors.

For a better design read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Just a doubt, I'm passing the "request.Content = new StringContent("Content-Type", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");". if I don't pass it, I won't be able to authenticate myself with the header. How do I use it?

Comment: And apart from the authentication, I did the same as you recommended. In "(json)" gave the following error:

Error CS1503 Argument 1: Cannot convert from "string" to "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader"

Comment: And thanks in advance for your help. I've been searching all day and no answers.

Comment: Look at the updated code and add your headers in the `Headers` section

Comment: It's giving this error in responseBody and asked for a return.

Erro CS1503 Argumento 1: não é possível converter de "string" para "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader"

Comment: If you want share the actual api url to give a try

Comment: This Api:
https://manairadigitalteste.conectala.com.br/app/Api/V1/Products/list

Comment: I edited and added the headers for authentication.

Comment: I can't access it because i am unauthorized

Comment: I was only able to authorize myself using "request.Content = new StringContent("Content-Type", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");". But with these headers that I passed in postman I can authenticate normally.

The code headers are wrong, the correct ones are in "edit2"

Comment: It needs to be authenticated. If you login will have the right claims to access the web api. Try login first via http client and you will get authenticated via cookies or via JWT. If this api uses cookie authentication then you will access the `/Products/list` endpoint otherwise you will get some token and you should add it as auth header

Comment: No code could authenticate me with the headers and the response.content that was passed. I just couldn't return the product list. But I managed to authenticate myself, I got the return code 200 (OK).

Comment: You need these headers: { "X-User-Email": "abc@abc.com" },
                                        { "X-User-Token": "12345678" }

Comment: I need to pass the 5 headers to authenticate myself. In Postman it works and in my posted code it is authenticating.

Comment: The correct headers are in EDIT2, you can see in postman that they authenticate.

Comment: The error message from response is clear: `{"success":false,"message":"Nem todos os cabeçalhos foram enviados. Cabeçalho ausente: x-user-email"}`

Comment: Refresh the token and i think you will be good to go. I mean relogin and get again this api key

Comment: This "x-api-key" does not change, nor is it generated and stored in the token. It is a static key that is in the API that I consume (They send it via email and it is static). Sorry if I don't understand what you're getting at

Comment: I believe there is something wrong because I got code 200 (authorized) with the headers passed like this: client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-user-email", "victor@teste.com.br");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", "eyJ0edsasa3121dasdas312dsa");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-store-key", "1");
                    request.Content = new StringContent("Content-Type", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

Comment: I believe this is it, I could be wrong.

Comment: Check now It works. I suggest you now to remove your credentials from the comments above

Comment: "responseBody" is giving error
Error CS1503 Argument 1: Cannot convert from "string" to "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader". And I return the responseBody itself? How is async I need to return something

Comment: Remove Newtonsoft and use System.Text.Json in order to have both the same code. In my end with the above code i was able to get the products from api. I used dotnet 6. Also check `x-store-key` to be 3

Comment: Just copy and paste the above code and you will get the results

Comment: I'm using MVC project and dotnet6. I ran it and it gave the error I put in "edit3".

Comment: I debugged by pressing F11 and I saw that I got a return, but I have this error. How to fix?

Comment: I debug line by line and saw that the error is being caused by the line "using var res = await client.SendAsync(req);" and my variable "root" is not getting value from Deserialize

Comment: Are your model classes same as here? Also you deserialize with text. json?

Comment: I dont know how to help you because with this piece of code it works for me

Comment: My code is exactly the same as yours, except for the method name which is "ListAsync()"

Comment: And I debugging in F11, I saw that in the end I don't get it deserialized. "root" returns null. But I believe it's because of the problem that is occurring in the line "using var res = await client.SendAsync(req)". Which is the line that opens the problem in the browser.

Comment: Just out of curiosity could you upload your project (or just this part) to a public repository on github to see why it doesn't even compile.

Comment: https://github.com/victormarconi/WebConsumoApi/tree/master/WebConsumoApi 


But I think the method we changed is outdated, but just copy the same.

Comment: Check the updated code again

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Wow thank you very much. You're the man, I really appreciate it. If you had a course I would definitely buy it. But thanks again.

Comment: Just one more question before I close the question. I also need to do get(id), create, update and delete. How would the get(id) method for example? Because the rest will be pretty much the same, but I'm not sure how to do get(id). As you may have seen in my code I even made the code, but it doesn't return the data.

Comment: I'm just not sure about it, I couldn't adapt. If you can help me to run get(id) I should be able to adapt the other methods.

Comment: This is something different from your original question. Just ask a new question because if we keep updating this post, people who visit it won't be able to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Okay, I'll ask a new question, thanks.

Comment: I asked the question, if you can help I would really appreciate it. the title is "Problem trying to use get(id). Can't get item return by id"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are right. I had same problem when deserialize the class. The problem is on you json when deserialize the object.Use this class when deserialize.

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public int offset { get; set; }
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public bool error { get; set; }
        public int registers_count { get; set; }
        public int pages_count { get; set; }
        public int page { get; set; }
        public Datum[] data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public Product product { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public int qty { get; set; }
        public float price { get; set; }
        public float? list_price { get; set; }
        public float weight_gross { get; set; }
        public float weight_liquid { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public string items_per_package { get; set; }
        public string brand { get; set; }
        public string ean { get; set; }
        public object ncm { get; set; }
        public Category[] categories { get; set; }
        public string[] variation_attributes { get; set; }
        public Variation[] variations { get; set; }
        public string[] images { get; set; }
        public Published_Marketplace published_marketplace { get; set; }
        public Marketplace_Offer_Links[] marketplace_offer_links { get; set; }
    }

    public class Published_Marketplace
    {
        public string ManairaDigital { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Variation
    {
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public int qty { get; set; }
        public object EAN { get; set; }
        public float price { get; set; }
        public float list_price { get; set; }
        public object[] images { get; set; }
        public Variant[] variant { get; set; }
    }

    public class Variant
    {
        public string size { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
    }

    public class Marketplace_Offer_Links
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).